# Secure String in Visual Basic, Imports & Module

Tags: vb.net, syntax, syntax-error

I'm experimenting with entering a password and have it stored as a secure string. I found the following code on MSDN.

```
Imports System.Security

Module Example
 Public Sub Main()
  ' Define the string value to be assigned to the secure string.
  Dim initString As String = "TestString"
  ' Instantiate the secure string.
  Dim testString As SecureString = New SecureString()
  ' Use the AppendChar method to add each char value to the secure string.
  For Each ch As Char In initString
     testString.AppendChar(ch)
  Next   
  ' Display secure string length.
  Console.WriteLine("The length of the string is {0} characters.", _ 
                    testString.Length)
  testString.Dispose()
 End Sub
End Module
' The example displays the following output:
'      The length of the string is 10 characters.
```

However I'm missing something as when I paste it in the Public Class element I get errors. The errors being as follows:

```
'Imports' statements must precede an declarations

'Module' statements can occur only at file or namespace level
```

I've tried putting the import statement before any `dim` statements in my other code this didn't help and also I'm unsure where I should be putting module (ie where is file or namespace level?)

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Your import statement cannot be inside a class, it must be on the first lines of your file. As well as your module declaration, it cannot be inside a class... A module is like a Shared class...

Comment: Sorry for this comment but please, if you have time, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: Thanks Martin, I know its a bit of a newbie question but thanks, little but important bits of info like this seem to be a nightmare to find via google.

Comment: @repairtech Well the first thing to do when you start working on a new language is to know how it works : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The structure of a file in VB .NET**

Your problem comes from the fact that you might not understand what is a class, a module, and so on... So let's review it...

For a complete review of the VB .NET : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

But it's kinda long...

**The Imports Statement**

This statement is here to say : "Hey Compiler, I am about to use some functions that you will find in this file, please link it to my file"

so `Imports System.Security` means that you import all classes and methods contained in namespace System.Security.

*Where to place it ?*

This statement is to placed at the very beggining of your .vb file. It cannot be inside anything else. The only things that can go before is the options (like ´Option Strict On´, but we won't discuss that here...).

**The Class Statement**

Placing a class statement means that you are creating a new "blueprint" for an object. You are about to define its methods, property and functionalities.

*Where to place it ?*

A class statement goes after the `Imports` declarations and can be placed inside a namespace, a module or another class

**The Module Statement**

A module in VB .NET in nothing else that a Shared Class. If you noticed, you cannot declare a Shared Class, you must declare a module instead.

*What does that mean ?*

It means that anything inside your module is accessible without having to instanciate any object. If your module offers the Test method :

```
Public Module MyModule
  Public Function Test() As String
    Return "Test"
  End Function
End Module
```

Then you can call that method by doing :

```
'... Anywhere in your code
MyModule.Test()
```

*Where to place it ?*

A module is like a class, however it **cannot** be placed inside another class. It must be placed inside a Namespace or in your file.

Hope this helps...

So basically

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Security

Namespace MyNamespace

  Public Module MyModule
    'My code here

     Public Class MyClassInsideAModule
       'My code here
     End Class
  End Module

  Public Class MyClass
    'My code here
    Public Class MyClassInsideAClass
      'My code here
    End Class
  End Class

End Namespace
```